Counting Tokens with Message History in OpenAI: Correct Approach?
Issues Identified on the Internet:

Websites like https://tiktokenizer.vercel.app/ are useful for counting tokens, but they seem to have limitations when memory is involved in the API, especially when handling both new and old messages.

There's a discrepancy in pricing between the message you send to the API and the output you receive, as shown in the screenshot below.

Source: https://openai.com/pricing.


Therefore, it's important to count them separately for a thorough cost analysis.
Here's my current approach (using GPT-3.5 Turbo):
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from openai import OpenAI
import tiktoken
import time
import os

load_dotenv()

example_messages = [{"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."}]

client = OpenAI(api_key=os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY"))

def gpt_response_func():
    response = client.chat.completions.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=example_messages
    )
    return response

token_count = {'input': 0, "output": 0, 'total': 0}

n = 1
while n <= 3:
    gpt_response = gpt_response_func()
    gpt_msg = gpt_response.choices[0].message.content
    gpt_token_usage = dict(gpt_response.usage)
    
    token_count['input'] += gpt_token_usage['prompt_tokens']
    token_count['output'] += gpt_token_usage['completion_tokens']
    token_count['total'] = token_count['input'] + token_count['output']
    
    print(token_count)
    print("Bot:", gpt_msg)
    example_messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": gpt_msg})
    
    time.sleep(2)
    user_response = input("User: ")
    print("User:", user_response)
    example_messages.append({"role": "user", "content": user_response})
    
    n += 1

I want to ensure if my approach is correct and seek suggestions for improvement. Additionally, if there's a better method available for dealing with token counting involving memory, I'd appreciate guidance as I couldn't find relevant resources online.
